# IBM Spectrum Scale Api /perfmon/data Regex for OR operation

Tags: regex, api

I am struggling to find the correct regex-expression for OR when using the Spectrum Scale (formerly GPFS) Version 5.0.3 API.

In Particular I wish to query for a key like

```
[curl options headers base-address...]/scalemgmt/v2/perfmon/data?query=key%20[..path...]|gpfs_pool_total[OR 'free']_dataKB%20[.. bucket etc]
```

This works for both individual metrics, but when I try to use any Regex like `(free|total)`,`(?:free|total)`,`[free|total]` as I would with console command access I fail.

The [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-scale/5.0.3?topic=get-querying-performance-data-by-using-perfmondata-request#bl1adm_apiv2getperfmonquery) tells me that I should be able to use them, however none of the Regex-Formats I use with monitoring commands like mmperfmon etc. seem to apply to API-requests.

Comment: The link you share does not provide details on the regex flavor used. If the above do not work for you, the only regex suggestion that comes to mind is `\(free\|total\)` GNU-like POSIX BRE regex, and if it is not accepted, it means you can't use a regex like this with alternation in that particular query. (Also, try adding `.*` on both ends to make sure the whole string is matched - sometimes whole string must match a regex).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, I also cannot find any comment on which Regex the API utilizes, hence I am struggling so much with it.
Your suggestions gave me `Error: cannot parse get query: parseMetricOp: invalid operation: dss.cluster|GPFSPool|[CLASSIFIED]|gpfs_pool_\\` like whenever I have enclosed brackets. Thanks anyway